# StringPattern: Not one of pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, replacement

I have read in a Mathematica notebook and have assigned its content to the variable `file`.

I have created the Strings corresponding to Wolfram Language symbols as follows:

```
wolframFunctions = #[[2]] & /@ WolframLanguageData[];
```

This list is nice, because I can now use it as an "or" StringPattern.

So if I wanted to find the amount each function is used in the file, I could do the following:

```
StringCases[
  StringJoin[ (*join notebook sections together *)
   Riffle[(ToString /@ (Flatten@NotebookImport@file)), "____"]], 
  wolframFunctions] // Tally

{{"Hold", 24}, {"C", 877}, {"All", 9}, {"Sin", 7}, {"N", 736}, {"Get",
   9}, {"D", 916}, {"Tr", 154}, {"E", 711}, {"Sec", 4}, {"Simplify", 
  4}, {"I", 841}, {"O", 471}, {"Re", 44}, {"Beta", 3}, {"Pi", 
  9}, {"Solve", 1}, {"Method", 57}, {"Accuracy", 1}, {"Precision", 
  23}, {"Table", 1}, {"List", 1}, {"Plot", 90}, {"Range", 
  74}, {"Style", 108}, {"Thick", 52}, {"Point", 1}, {"Large", 
  1}, {"BaseStyle", 30}, {"Axes", 74}, {"Label", 52}, {"Failure", 
  2}, {"BoxData", 2}, {"RawBoxes", 1}, {"Row", 278}, {"TagBox", 
  176}, {"TemplateBox", 11}, {"Function", 110}, {"Sum", 198}, {"Head",
   11}, {"Mod", 22}, {"False", 231}, {"Pane", 44}, {"Select", 
  33}, {"Grid", 198}, {"Button", 44}, {"Front", 22}, {"Square", 
  22}, {"Plus", 11}, {"Medium", 22}, {"Appearance", 22}, {"Automatic",
   275}, {"Alignment", 66}, {"Graph", 30}, {"RGBColor", 44}, {"Abs", 
  66}, {"Line", 92}, {"AspectRatio", 22}, {"Frame", 88}, {"Tiny", 
  22}, {"Ticks", 44}, {"Gray", 22}, {"Level", 22}, {"BoundaryStyle", 
  22}, {"ScalingFunctions", 22}, {"Padding", 22}, {"Scale", 
  88}, {"Annotation", 77}, {"Left", 22}, {"AutoDelete", 
  44}, {"Spacings", 22}, {"Show", 44}, {"String", 22}, {"Print", 
  22}, {"Top", 22}, {"Baseline", 44}, {"Position", 33}, {"Min", 
  11}, {"Values", 11}, {"With", 11}, {"Times", 1}, {"Magnification", 
  44}, {"Hue", 2}}
```

where a snippet of the above notebook (`file`) is:

```
"HoldComplete[ClearAll[Global`*]]____HoldComplete[Rx[\[Theta]_] := \
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {0, Sin[\[Theta]], \
Cos[\[Theta]]}}; , Null, Ry[\[Theta]_] := {{Cos[\[Theta]], 0, Sin[\
\[Theta]]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[\[Theta]], 0, Cos[\[Theta]]}}; , Null, \
Rz[\[Theta]_] := {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {Sin[\[Theta]], \
Cos[\[Theta]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}; ]____HoldComplete[GetWx[Rmt_] := \
D[Rmt, t] . Transpose[Rmt]; , Null, GetW[Rmt_] := \
{{GetWx[Rmt][[3]][[2]]}, {GetWx[Rmt][[1]][[3]]}, \
{GetWx[Rmt][[2]][[1]]}}; ]____HoldComplete[(EsfPrimRot = \
Rz[\[Psi]sph[t]]; ) (EsfSecRot = Ry[\[Theta]sph[t]]; ) (EsfTerRot = \
Rx[\[Phi]sph[t]]; ) (PendSecRot = Ry[\[Alpha]pend[t]]; ) (PendPrimRot \
= Rx[\[Beta]pend[t]]; )]____HoldComplete[REsf = EsfPrimRot . \
EsfSecRot . EsfTerRot; , Null, RPend = REsf . PendPrimRot . \
PendSecRot; ]____HoldComplete[DVecPend = RPend . {{0}, {0}, \
{-radioPendulo}}; ]____HoldComplete[(\[CapitalOmega]Esf = \
Simplify[-GetW[Transpose[REsf]]]; ) (\[Omega]Esf = \
Simplify[GetW[REsf]]; ) (\[CapitalOmega]Pend = \
Simplify[-GetW[Transpose[RPend]]]; ) (\[Omega]Pend = \
Simplify[GetW[RPend]]; )]____HoldComplete[(InertiaPendulo = {{IxxP, \
0, 0}, {0, IyyP, 0}, {0, 0, IzzP}}; ) (InertiaSph = {{IxxS, 0, 0}, \
{0, IyyS, 0}, {0, 0, IzzS}}; )]____HoldComplete[(EROTESF = 0.5 \
(Transpose[\[CapitalOmega]Esf] . InertiaSph . \
\[CapitalOmega]Esf)[[1]][[1]]; ) (EROTPEND = 0.5 (Transpose[\
\[CapitalOmega]Pend] . InertiaPendulo . \
\[CapitalOmega]Pend)[[1]][[1]]; )]____HoldComplete[VecEsfera = \
{{x[t]}, {y[t]}, {radioEsfera}}; ]"
```

and it goes on for a long while with sections and plots, etc

But how could I StringReplace all *not* `wolframFunctions` with something like `"NotASymbol"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79636/discussion-between-creidhne-and-sumneuron).

Comment: You could do something like: `Tally @ Cases[NotebookImport[file, 
  "Input"], _Symbol?(Context[#] === "System`" &), {3, Infinity}, 
 Heads -> True]`

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem using the `snippet` and `StringCases[snippet, wolframFunctions] // Tally`. It finds these strings:

> {{"Hold", 10}, {"C", 17}, {"All", 1}, {"Sin", 6}, {"N", 5}, {"Get",
>   9}, {"D", 3}, {"Tr", 5}, {"E", 20}, {"Sec", 4}, {"Simplify",    4},
>   {"I", 10}, {"O", 2}}

But notice that we found `C` instead of `ClearAll` or `Cos`, `Hold` instead of `HoldComplete`, `N` instead of `Null`, and `Tr` but not `Transpose`. These shorter symbols are not in the snippet.

Instead, make a list of patterns that match `wolframFunctions`.

```
wolframPatterns = 
  StringExpression[WordBoundary, #, WordBoundary] & /@ wolframFunctions;
```

Then use `StringCases` to match the patterns which makes a better list of matching Wolfram Language symbols:

```
(myFunctions = StringCases[snippet, wolframPatterns]) // Tally
```

> {{"HoldComplete", 1}, {"ClearAll", 1}, {"Cos", 6}, {"Sin",    6},
>   {"Null", 4}, {"D", 1}, {"Transpose", 5}, {"Simplify", 4}}

With the improved list of matching functions, let's find `"NotASymbol"`, meaning, strings that are not Wolfram Language symbols:

```
myStrings = 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  StringCases[snippet, 
   WordBoundary ~~ WordCharacter .. ~~ WordBoundary];
Complement[myStrings, DeleteDuplicates@myFunctions]
```

> $\{0,1,2,3,5,\text{DVecPend},\text{EROTESF},\text{EROTPEND},\text{EsfPrimRot},\text{EsfSecRot},\text{EsfTerRot},\text{GetW},\text{GetWx},\text{Global},\text{InertiaPendulo},\text{InertiaSph},\text{IxxP},\text{IxxS},\text{IyyP},\text{IyyS},\text{IzzP},\text{IzzS},\text{PendPrimRot},\text{PendSecRot},\text{radioEsfera},\text{radioPendulo},\text{REsf},\text{Rmt},\text{RPend},\text{Rx},\text{Ry},\text{Rz},\text{t},\text{VecEsfera},\text{x},\text{y},\text{$\alpha $pend},\text{$\beta $pend},\theta ,\text{$\theta$sph},\text{$\phi$sph},\text{$\psi $sph},\text{$\omega $Esf},\text{$\Omega$Esf},\text{$\omega $Pend},\text{$\Omega $Pend}\}$